# What do you call a **person** who is capable of doing anything and everything, humanly possible?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call a **person** who is capable of doing anything and everything, humanly possible?

Comment: _Jack/Jill of all trades._

Answer (score 1):

I've always referred to them as a "Jack of all trades".

"Jack of all trades, master of none" is a figure of speech used in reference to a person who has dabbled in many skills, rather than gaining expertise by focusing on one.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_of_all_trades,_master_of_none

Answer (score 0):

[Polymath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymath) or Renaissance man

> A polymath (Greek: πολυμαθής, polymathēs, "having learned much"; Latin: homo universalis, "universal man")[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymath) is an individual whose knowledge spans a substantial number of subjects, known to draw on complex bodies of knowledge to solve specific problems.
> ...
> Polymaths include the great scholars and thinkers of the Islamic Golden Age, Renaissance and Enlightenment, who excelled at several fields in science, technology, engineering, mathematics, and the arts. In the Italian Renaissance, the idea of the polymath was expressed by Leon Battista Alberti (1404–1472) in the statement that "a man can do all things if he will".[8] Gottfried Wilhelm Leibniz has often been seen as a polymath.
>
> Embodying a basic tenet of Renaissance humanism that humans are limitless in their capacity for development, the concept led to the notion that people should embrace all knowledge and develop their capacities as fully as possible. This is expressed in the term Renaissance man, often applied to the gifted people of that age who sought to develop their abilities in all areas of accomplishment: intellectual, artistic, social, physical, and spiritual.

Comment: *Polymath* has distinctively intellectual overtones. The question doesn't ask anything of that sort in particular.